# is conversation.id for ms teams bot unique?

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

In ms teams bot. for group chat and for personal chat, I received following conversation object.

```
conversation: {
  isGroup: true,
  conversationType: 'groupChat',
  tenantId: '3fef5931-0c12-4eb9-b22f-xxxxxxx',
  id: '19:abad7298-34e2-4437-ad7d-xxxxxxxxxxxx-224f-4e50-xxxxxxde65@unq.gbl.spaces'
},

conversation: {
  conversationType: 'personal',
  tenantId: '3fef59xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd03d',
  id: 'a:1fIazkAU3MCwYcbsr1nZcpg_VTMw8OuWxxxxxxxxxxxxKKVpzEgbeiqrnT3B8eM856iyI6G61qoeXU0UXt7XkGpbmi0As9-mV1h2Ywz-Coi'
},
```

1. Is the **id** for both the conversation unique ? Do the **id** changes in case of personal or group chat after some days ?
2. Can i use it as unique identifier ?

Comment: Conversation id is unique. It will not change when time passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**->Do the id changes in case of personal or group chat after some days ?**

No, it doesn't change after few days. The only time it changes is when you re-add the bot to channel.

**->Can I use it as unique identifier ?**

**->Is the id for both the conversation unique ?**
Answer for above two questions is detailed out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#conversation-id)